If $a_n\ge 0$ and $a_n\to 0$ and also $\sum a_n=\infty$, then $\sum \left(1-\left|\frac{a_n -1}{a_n +1}\right|\right) = \infty$
Good Afternoon!
am trying to understand a well known research paper, I came across the following lines, which let me assume that the conjecture is pretty "standard" or  well known, however, I don't know the name of the series and have no clue what to google to better understand them:
If there is a series $\{a_n\}$ with $a_n \geq 0$ and $\lim a_n \rightarrow 0$ and the series $\sum_{i=1}^{\infty}a_n = \infty$, then the series $\sum_{i=1}^{\infty} \left( 1 - \left|\frac{a_n -1}{a_n+1}\right|\right) = \infty$, diverges too.
Does anyone know the name of the series above? -- looks similar to Blaschke products?!
Or any idea, in which book to look for some more explanation about it?
cheers
John

Since $a_n\to 0$, then $a_n<1$, whenever $n\ge n_0$, for a suitable $n_0\in\mathbb N$. In particular, $\dfrac{1}{1+a_n}> \dfrac{1}{2}$, whenever $n\ge n_0$. Hence
$$ 
\sum_{i=n_0}^n \left( 1 - \left|\frac{a_i -1}{a_i+1}\right|\right) 
=\sum_{i=n_0}^n \left( 1 - \frac{1-a_i}{1+a_i}\right) 
=\sum_{i=n_0}^n \frac{2a_i}{1+a_i} >\sum_{i=n_0}^n \frac{2a_i}{2}
=\sum_{i=n_0}^n a_i \to \infty
$$

I was typing this answer about 3 hours ago, but got distracted by life. Great minds and all that :)

This is great! Thank you very much! Very well explained! :-)

$$
1 - |\frac{a_n - 1}{a_n + 1}| = 1 - \frac{|a_n - 1|}{|a_n + 1|} = 1 - \frac{|a_n - 1||a_n + 1|}{|a_n + 1|^2} = \frac{a_{n}^2 + 2a_n + 1}{(a_n + 1)^2} - \frac{|a_{n}^2 - 1|}{(a_n + 1)^2} > \frac{a_{n}^2 + 2a_n + 1}{(1 + a_n)^2} - \frac{a_{n}^2}{(a_n + 1)^2} = \frac{2a_n + 1}{(a_n + 1)^2}
$$
and the limit of this sequence does not converge to $0$, hence its infinite series diverges and the result follows.

@RyszardSzwarc Thank you, good catch!

@RyszardSzwarc: what does this show? that for $a_n = n^2$ is converges to zero? so what?
